# Racket FFI -- example of C array (_array) usage?

Tags: arrays, racket, ffi

I'm wrapping a C function that takes a pointer as an argument and treats it either as an int pointer, a float pointer, or an array of ints or floats, depending on another argument. The function is part of renderer in a game, and is called many (60+) times per second.

So with that said, I know I can use `_list` to pass array type argument, but

- it fragments the heap? If I understand it correctly, racket calls `malloc` before each invocation, and `free` right after
- it needs a specific type, so I would then have to create 2 functions (one for `_int`, one for `_float`), which wouldn't be ideal

I stumbled across https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Array_Types.html , and it seems exactly what I want -- both more efficient ("The array is not copied; the Racket representation is backed by the underlying C representation") and also suitable for more than one type ("it can have a different element type as long as that type matches the layout of the expected type").

Problem is, I can't seem find a way how to construct it from Racket side? These all statements return `#f`, and I'm out of ideas

```
#lang racket

(require ffi/unsafe)

(displayln (array? (make-array-type _float 5)))
(displayln (array? (_array _float 5)))
(displayln (array? (malloc (_array _float 5))))
(displayln (array? (malloc (make-array-type _float 5))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make-array-type` and `_array` functions create [C types](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/types.html#%28tech._c._type%29), which are plain Racket run-time values that describe how to convert kinds of values to and from C-level representations: for example, `_unt8` is a C type. The predicate `array?` recognizes actual values that are represented with an `_array`-based C type, not the C type itself.

As far as constructing an array value, [the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Array_Types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25foreign%29._make-array-type%29%29) say:

> Since an array is treated like a struct, casting a pointer type to an array type does not work. Instead, use ptr-ref with a pointer, an array type constructed with _array, and index 0 to convert a pointer to a Racket representation that works with array-ref and array-set!.

Here's how that works in practice—the docs could use an example:

```lisp
#lang racket

(require ffi/unsafe
         rackunit)

(define 5floats (_array _float 5))

(check-true
 (array? (ptr-ref (malloc 5floats) 5floats)))
```

For future reference, the Racket community is much more active on the racket-users mailing list and Slack than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Somehow I misunderstood that bit in the docs.

Comment: (Side note I didn't manage to pass float array in place of int array as I hoped to, but I won't bother with it anymore and just declare the type as _pointer as the function parameter type)